# How to show row repetition in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am trying to work out a query for a `transaction` table with data as shown below:

| Dept | Employee | TransactionDate | Event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dept1 | emp1 | 2022-05-20 | abgd |
| dept1 | emp1 | 2022-05-20 | ggg |
| dept1 | emp1 | 2022-05-20 | hdfh |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 | 3fdfds |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 | dsfsd |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 | 554fsds |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 | gg32 |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 | fd4gfg |

I would like to list the **count** the no. of times the Dept+Employee+TransactionDate is repeated for each event as shown below:

| Dept | Employee | TransactionDate | Event | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dept1 | emp1 | 2022-05-20 | abgd | 3 |
| dept1 | emp1 | 2022-05-20 | ggg | 3 |
| dept1 | emp1 | 2022-05-20 | hdfh | 3 |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 | 3fdfds | 5 |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 | dsfsd | 5 |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 | 554fsds | 5 |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 | gg32 | 5 |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 | fd4gfg | 5 |

I am looking a way to get the expected view. If it's possible with a single sql query?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `COUNT` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept, Employee, TransactionDate) AS cnt
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Dept, Employee, TransactionDate, Event) AS
SELECT 'dept1', 'emp1', DATE '2022-05-20', 'abgd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dept1', 'emp1', DATE '2022-05-20', 'ggg' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dept1', 'emp1', DATE '2022-05-20', 'hdfh' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dept2', 'emp2', DATE '2022-01-26', '3fdfds' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dept2', 'emp2', DATE '2022-01-26', 'dsfsd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dept2', 'emp2', DATE '2022-01-26', '554fsds' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dept2', 'emp2', DATE '2022-01-26', 'gg32' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dept2', 'emp2', DATE '2022-01-26', 'fd4gfg' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DEPT | EMPLOYEE | TRANSACTIONDATE | EVENT | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dept1 | emp1 | 2022-05-20 00:00:00 | abgd | 3 |
| dept1 | emp1 | 2022-05-20 00:00:00 | hdfh | 3 |
| dept1 | emp1 | 2022-05-20 00:00:00 | ggg | 3 |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 00:00:00 | gg32 | 5 |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 00:00:00 | 554fsds | 5 |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 00:00:00 | dsfsd | 5 |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 00:00:00 | fd4gfg | 5 |
| dept2 | emp2 | 2022-01-26 00:00:00 | 3fdfds | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b1aOAUpy)